# Error when installing ROS for Nao robot

Tags: ros, nao-robot, nao, cross-compiling, cross-compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone manage to install the ros for the nao robot?
I am experiencing problems with the installation process. I am installing using the NAO sdk 1.12.3 (geode).
For the environment setup (on the website)

```
export GEODE_CXX=$CTC_DIR/cross/geode/bin/i586-linux-g++
export GEODE_CC=$CTC_DIR/cross/geode/bin/i586-linux-gcc
```

to

```
export GEODE_CXX=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-g++
export GEODE_CC=$CTC_DIR/cross/bin/i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
```

the compilation errors:

```
  -- QI_SDK_DIR: /home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/build/sdk
  -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 
  [rosbuild] Building package roslib
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
  [rosbuild] Including /home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/bin/rosboost-cfg", line 35, in <module>
      rosboost_cfg.main()
    File "/home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/tools/rosboost_cfg/src/rosboost_cfg/rosboost_cfg.py", line 326, in main
      raise BoostError("Cannot find boost in any of %s"%search_paths(options.sysroot))
  rosboost_cfg.rosboost_cfg.BoostError: "Cannot find boost in any of [('/home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/build/sdk/usr', True), ('/home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/build/sdk/usr/local', True)]"
  CMake Error at /home/anshar/nao/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:881 (message):
    rosboost-cfg --include_dirs failed
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:10 (rosbuild_add_boost_directories)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38716/error-when-installing-ros-for-nao-robot/) by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 128 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daniel_maier](https://answers.ros.org/users/957/daniel_maier/) on 2012-07-12**:
What version of ROS are you trying to compile? What command caused that error message?

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-07-17**:
im trying to install ros base (ros electric) for Cross-Compiling ROS for the Nao. I install it by referring to http://www.ros.org/wiki/nao/Tutorials/Cross-Compiling . the error generated when compile ROS (Stage 6) with the command:cd ros && make clean && make.

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-07-31**:
I managed to compile it.Thanks

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-31**:
Could you post your solution as an answer, so others can benefit from it as well?

**Comment by [ryann2k1](https://answers.ros.org/users/2312/ryann2k1/) on 2012-08-09**:
im directing the ros boost root to directory of ctc/sysroot/usr and also including the ros boost version which is mine is 1.45.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer from ryan2k1's comment:

Set the ros boost root to the directory of ctc/sysroot/usr and include the Boost version 1.45.0

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1